# How can i check my Windows Phone Messages in outlook

Tags: sms

Previously I have an option to check my text messages in outlook.

When i tried with the link it is opening my outlook mails.

Is there any way to check my text messages or to backup?

Answer (score 0):

There is a separate messaging app which will allow you check your text messages or SMS.

Go to all apps list, open /messaging app.

For backing up messages you can use the app [Transfer My Data](https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/store/apps/Transfer-my-Data/9WZDNCRFJ3DR) by Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

Not anymore it seems. Maybe it'll come back.

---

### There's another way

You can ask Cortana to sync messages (notifications) between the phone and computer, then you can reply to messages from the computer.

1. Open **Cortana**
2. Go to **Settings**
3. Enable *Send notifications between devices*